# ImageDataBunch.from_df positional indexers are out-of-bounds

Tags: python-3.x, kaggle, fast-ai

scratching my head on this issue. i dont know how to identify the positional indexers. am i even passing them?

attempting this for my first kaggle comp, can pass in the csv to a dataframe and make the needed edits. trying to create the ImageDataBunch so training a cnn can begin. This error pops up no matter which method is tried. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
data = ImageDataBunch.from_df(path, df, ds_tfms=tfms, size=24)
data.classes
```

Backtrace

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-5588812820e8> in <module>
----> 1 data = ImageDataBunch.from_df(path, df, ds_tfms=tfms, size=24)
      2 data.classes

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastai/vision/data.py in from_df(cls, path, df, folder, label_delim, valid_pct, seed, fn_col, label_col, suffix, **kwargs)
    117         src = (ImageList.from_df(df, path=path, folder=folder, suffix=suffix, cols=fn_col)
    118                 .split_by_rand_pct(valid_pct, seed)
--> 119                 .label_from_df(label_delim=label_delim, cols=label_col))
    120         return cls.create_from_ll(src, **kwargs)
    121 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastai/data_block.py in _inner(*args, **kwargs)
    477         assert isinstance(fv, Callable)
    478         def _inner(*args, **kwargs):
--> 479             self.train = ft(*args, from_item_lists=True, **kwargs)
    480             assert isinstance(self.train, LabelList)
    481             kwargs['label_cls'] = self.train.y.__class__

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastai/data_block.py in label_from_df(self, cols, label_cls, **kwargs)
    283     def label_from_df(self, cols:IntsOrStrs=1, label_cls:Callable=None, **kwargs):
    284         "Label `self.items` from the values in `cols` in `self.inner_df`."
--> 285         labels = self.inner_df.iloc[:,df_names_to_idx(cols, self.inner_df)]
    286         assert labels.isna().sum().sum() == 0, f"You have NaN values in column(s) {cols} of your dataframe, please fix it."
    287         if is_listy(cols) and len(cols) > 1 and (label_cls is None or label_cls == MultiCategoryList):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1760                 except (KeyError, IndexError, AttributeError):
   1761                     pass
-> 1762             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1763         else:
   1764             # we by definition only have the 0th axis

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
   2065     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup: Tuple):
   2066 
-> 2067         self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
   2068         try:
   2069             return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _has_valid_tuple(self, key)
    701                 raise IndexingError("Too many indexers")
    702             try:
--> 703                 self._validate_key(k, i)
    704             except ValueError:
    705                 raise ValueError(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_key(self, key, axis)
   2007             # check that the key does not exceed the maximum size of the index
   2008             if len(arr) and (arr.max() >= len_axis or arr.min() < -len_axis):
-> 2009                 raise IndexError("positional indexers are out-of-bounds")
   2010         else:
   2011             raise ValueError(f"Can only index by location with a [{self._valid_types}]")

IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this error while creating a DataBunch when my dataframe/CSV did not have a class label explicitly defined.

I created a dummy column which stored 1's for all my rows in the dataframe and it seemed to work. Also please be sure to store your independent variable in the second column and the label(dummy variable in this case) in the first column.

I believe this error happens if there's just one column in the Pandas DataFrame.

Thanks.

Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(lines, columns=["dummy_value", "text"])
df.to_csv("./train.csv")
data_lm = TextLMDataBunch.from_csv(path, "train.csv", min_freq=1)
```

Note: This is my first attempt at answering a StackOverflow question. Hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

This error also appears when your dataset is not correctly split between test and validation.

In the case of dataframes, it assumes there is a column `is_valid` that indicates which rows are in validation set.

If all rows have `True`, then the training set is empty, so fastai cannot index into it to prepare the first example, thus raising this error.

Example:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'fname': [f'{x}.png' for x in range(10)], 
    'label': np.arange(10)%2, 
    'is_valid': True
})
blk = DataBlock((ImageBlock, CategoryBlock),
                splitter=ColSplitter(),
                get_x=ColReader('fname'),
                get_y=ColReader('label'),
                item_tfms=Resize(224, method=ResizeMethod.Squish),
)

blk.summary(data)
```

Results in the error.

### Solution

The solution is to check that your data can be split correctly into train and valid sets. In the above example, it suffices to have one row that is not in validation set:

```
data.loc[0, 'is_valid'] = False
```

### How to figure it out?

Work in a jupyter notebook. After the error, type `%debug` in a cell, and enter the post mortem debugging. Go to the frame of the setup function ( `fastai/data/core.py(273) setup()` ) by going `up 5` frames.

This takes you to [this line](https://github.com/fastai/fastai/blob/351f4b9314e2ea23684fb2e19235ee5c5ef8cbfd/fastai/data/core.py#L272) that is throwing the error.

You can then `print(self.splits)` and observe that the first one is empty.